# SQL Server to find the current and next value using row count

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query. I'm creating different metrics. Any idea how could I create Abandon # by similar logic like TotalLogic#?

The actual logic to create the abandon # is as follows:

- Quantity of self-service username recovery that starts but does not successfully complete in the same day.

Logic query for abandon#

```
EventSource = ’Customer’ 
and EventName = ‘Login’ 
and EventType = ’ForgotEmail’
and StatusDetail = ‘Screen:AboutYou _NextButton;Zip:<>’
___ AND __
EventSource = ’Customer’
EventName = ’Login’ 
and EventType = ’ForgotEmail’ 
and StatusDetail = ’Status: Status:RetrieveEmailSuccessful
```

My current query

```
SELECT 
    ab.TransactionDate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN EventSource = 'Customer' AND EventName = 'Login' AND EventType = 'Standard' AND StatusDesc = 'Success'  
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalLogin#,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EventSource = 'Customer' AND EventName = 'Login' AND EventType = 'ForgotEmail'  
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Abandon#
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         p.TransactionDate, p.PolicyNumber, p.UserId,
         p.CustomerBrand, p.EventSource, p.EventName, p.EventType,
         p.Status, p.StatusDetail, p.StatusDesc,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.PolicyNumber ORDER BY p.TransactionDate) AS row_count_policy,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.UserId ORDER BY p.TransactionDate) AS row_count_user_id 
     FROM 
         [iso_report].[dbo].[PACE_Service_Log_support] p WITH (nolock)
     WHERE  
         ISNULL(EventSource, '') IN ('Customer')
         AND ISNULL(EventName, '') IN ('Login')
         AND CAST(Transactiondate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-1-1') ab 
GROUP BY 
    ab.TransactionDate
```

Comment: What is the point of this? "CAST(Transactiondate AS DATE) BETWEEN  '2017-01-01' AND '2017-1-1'" Why use between here? Why not simply =. And why two different string formats for dates? As for the question at hand....well....what is the question?

Comment: Based on your description, perhaps you need an `EXISTS`?